# Refering to the same key twice in Typescript Generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a type `A` where keys are strings and values are some datatype. (see below)

Now I want to create a `Map<K,V>` where `K` is a key of `A` and `V` is of the **corresponding** datatype in `A`. (see my attempt below)

```
type A = {
  a: boolean,
  b: number,
};

const myMap: Map<keyof A, A[keyof A]> = new Map();
myMap.set('a', 1); // bad

// only this should be allowed:
myMap.set('a', true);
myMap.set('b', 1);
```

My approach doesn't work since the first `keyof A` must not necessarily be the same as the second `keyof A`. What is the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: `typeof keyof A…`

Comment: `Map<K, V>` isn't strongly typed enough for you to represent this (much like `Record<K, V>` can't represent arbitrary object types).  See the answer to the linked question for more information; if I use the `ObjectMap<T>` typings from there I get [this code](https://tsplay.dev/mLqL4W).  At runtime that's still a `Map` (in the JavaScript sense) but the TypeScript typings are typed to expect object key-value pairs.  Not sure I've ever really understood the use case for this over just a plain object, though.

Comment: The Map problem was just an example and occurs in other scenarios as well.